# Return fails despite everything else in conditional working

Tags: python-2.7, return, conditional-statements

I wrote a simple recursive function to test whether a is a power of b.

```
def is_power(a, b):
""" returns True if a is a power of b"""
    if a == b:
        print('True!')
        return True
    elif a%b != 0:
        return False
    elif a != b and a%b == 0:
        is_power(a/b, b)
```

When I run it on a case that should return True, it doesn't return anything, even though it executes other commands from the same if statement as the return statement.

> is_power(8,2)
>   True!

I assume I'm doing something stupid / missing something blindingly obvious. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last alternative is missing 'return'

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are returning is_power(a/b, b) like so:

```
def is_power(a, b): 
    if a == b:
        return True
    elif a%b != 0:
        return False
    elif a != b and a%b == 0:
        return is_power(a/b, b)

print(is_power(9,2))
```